# Dummy output on Pulse after Upgrade - Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC663 Analog [ALC663 Analog]

Tags: pulseaudio, realtek

I really need some help here - Dummy output after upgrade.

I'll get to the point, I've had this error time and time again with Debian, and I know it's because of the Intel Integrated Soundchip, but I've never been able to fix it, no matter what Debian Distro I've used. Over the years, I've either done a reinstall or just installed a new distro, but that's like cracking a nut with a sledgehammer.

I'm currently using Emmabuntüs, and I really like the distro so I want to fix this issue. I've gone through many a page and site with a fix but none of them have worked.

I'm proficient in using bash and whatnot, so the more technical your answer, the better.

Also, FYI, when I right click on the volume applet at thetop, PulseAudio is greyed out, so to me that means that it's not loaded for some reason (`pulseaudio -k` returns "no such process", to back that up). I've reinstalled Pulse but to no avail.

`dmesg | grep snd` returns:

```
[   21.019181] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: Applying patch firmware 'hda-jack-retask.fw'
[   21.289339] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware hda-jack-retask.fw
[   21.525724] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2: autoconfig for ALC663: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   21.525737] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   21.525741] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   21.525746] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   21.525748] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:    inputs:
[   21.525751] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Front Mic=0x19
[   21.525755] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Rear Mic=0x18
[   21.525758] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D2:      Line=0x1a
```

Please help!!